# How to benchmark two Anaconda environments using TensorFlow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I got tired of all the reminders that TensorFlow is not optimized for my CPU and so finally compiled it from source. In fact I did it twice and made two `.whl` files, once using

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

and once using

```
bazel build --config=mkl --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

since I was not sure how much difference the `Intel MKL` would make. Now I have setup two identical anaconda environments, one using each `whl` file.

What is the quickest way to determine which of the `.whl` packages performs better on my system? If someone can point me to a standard Benchmark package/command in tensorflow that would be great (please note that I do not have GPU support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the below benchmark and check the performance.

https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks.git

git clone the above code to your terminal and then run the tf_cnn_benchmark.py benchmark code.

Thanks

Comment: Wow. Seems using `MKL` is slower. Without MKL: `total images/sec: 216.37` and with MKL: `total images/sec: 103.11`